# Hasura permissions missing "_in" operator

Tags: hasura

According to [this post](https://hasura.io/blog/support-for-array-operators-in-permissions/), Hasura has the "_in" operation in permissions.

I'm currently running Hasura 2.1.1, but none of the new operators described in that post are present:

[image]

Looking around on the internet I found no mention of this, but maybe this is because I'm using the open-source edition?

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: What database are you using with hasura?

Comment: I would check that your console is up to date as that feature is not effected by [different editions][1].

On a new Hasura Cloud instance I created a table named "test" with a uuid column named "id"

On the permissions page on a custom check on "id" I have the _in operator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKtIt.jpg

Can you try my same table setup and see if it works? For further help I'd join the Hasura discord

  [1]: https://hasura.io/products/

Comment: I'm using big query in this case

Comment: @ArjunYelamanchili I will try using a postgres DB on my hosted instance to see if the option appear

Comment: I'm having the same problem using a SQL Server database...is this not supported?

Comment: There's an issue (https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/7609) but no response yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with BigQuery itself
In this case I solved switching to Postgres